# Storing historical records and extracting data from a given period

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-theory, erd

This a question about database modeling and PostgreSQL. This [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/131624/48623) partially answers the question but I need advice on more technical stuff: columns and query to extract the data.

I need to store administrative boundaries history within a given territory in order to be able to track boundaries movements back over the passed years.

Here is an example on how boundaries move:

- *Martin Land* area has always existed
- *Bulwers Land* area has always existed too
- Those areas were merged together in 2015:

  - The new area was renamed as *Martin-Bulwers*
  - The new area kept *Bulwers Land* code (*Martin Land* code becoming deprecated)

Here is the way I store the data:

```
gid  | code   | name            | change_date
-----+--------+-----------------+-------------
1    | 86001  | Martin Land     | 2000-01-01
2    | 86002  | Bulwers Land    | 2000-01-01
3    | 86002  | Martin-Bulwers  | 2015-01-01
```

I have set a default `change_date` to `2000-01-01` for historical situation of an area, i.e. before the first changement occurs.

Then, I have many different cases: areas that have remained unmerged, areas that have merged with others at different dates. This can produce the following example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS
SELECT gid,code,area,change_date::date FROM ( VALUES
  ( 1,86001,'Martin Land'   ,'2000-01-01' ),
  ( 2,86002,'Bulwers Land'  ,'2000-01-01' ),
  ( 3,86002,'Martin-Bulwers','2015-01-01' ),
  ( 4,86003,'Coveral Land'  ,'2000-01-01' ),
  ( 5,86004,'Big Tom Area'  ,'2000-01-01' ),
  ( 6,86005,'Small Tom Area','2000-01-01' ),
  ( 7,86004,'Tom Land'      ,'2016-01-01' )
) AS t(gid,code,area,change_date);
```

Then I have difficulties writing a query that could return **the list of areas of a given year**. I tried to rely on `DISTINCT ON()` clause but this does not the job I need...

For instance, the following query will return the following table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (code) code, area, change_date

  FROM myTable WHERE change_date < '2016-01-01'

  ORDER BY code, change_date DESC ;

-- Result:

code   | area            | change_date
-------+-----------------+-------------
86001  | Martin Land     | 2000-01-01
86002  | Martin-Bulwers  | 2015-01-01
86003  | Coveral Land    | 2000-01-01
86004  | Big Tom Area    | 2000-01-01
86005  | Small Tom Area  | 2000-01-01
```

This is partially right as before `2016-01-01`, *Big Tom Area* and *Small Tom Area* had not merged together but *Martin Land* and *Bulwers Land* had! There were 5 areas in 2014, then 4 areas in 2015 and 3 in 2016.

In fact, I would need the following result:

```
code   | area            | change_date
-------+-----------------+-------------
86002  | Martin-Bulwers  | 2015-01-01
86003  | Coveral Land    | 2000-01-01
86004  | Big Tom Area    | 2000-01-01
86005  | Small Tom Area  | 2000-01-01
```

Is there another way to store these informations or to write the query?

Comment: This is an especially bad data schema: what you want is something hierarchical, and what you've got is crap: the Martin-Bulwers plot is a descendant of Martin Land, **and** Bulwers Land. It's especially hard to infer that because you have nothing that designates which nodes are root plots.  Are the root plots all `2000-01-01`? In your example above, how do we infer that `Coveral Land` is separate from all the other sets? Because it *both* COMES BEFORE, and has a ID AFTER?

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. How come Tom Land has a 86004 and not 86005 (greater than or equal to it's ancestors) and Mart-Bulwers has 86002 while it's two ancestors have 86001 and 86002. How do you link Tom Land to Small Tom Area when Small Tom Area has a newer id, but an older date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution I finally adopted and that prove to be right enough for my needs and that avoid using `infinity` date statement.

```
 gid  | code | name            | start_date | end_date   | parent
 -----+------+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------
 1    | 86001| Martin Land     | 2000-01-01 | 2014-12-31 |
 2    | 86002| Bulwers Land    | 2000-01-01 | 2014-12-31 |
 3    | 86002| Martin-Bulwers  | 2015-01-01 | 2100-01-01 | {86001,86002}
```

I added a `parent` column to store the codes of former areas that merged to produce the new area. I also use a `start_date` and `end_date` columns.

Then, the following queries enable to select the areas of a given year:

```
-- Year 2015
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date <= '2015-01-01' AND end_date >= '2015-01-01' ;

-- Result:

 gid  | code | name            | start_date | end_date   | parent
 -----+------+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------
 3    | 86002| Martin-Bulwers  | 2015-01-01 | 2100-01-01 | {86001,86002}


-- Year 2012
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date <= '2012-01-01' AND end_date >= '2012-01-01' ;

-- Result:

 gid  | code | name            | start_date | end_date   | parent
 -----+------+-----------------+------------+------------+-----------
 1    | 86001| Martin Land     | 2000-01-01 | 2014-12-31 |
 2    | 86002| Bulwers Land    | 2000-01-01 | 2014-12-31 |
```

Of course, I set a `start_date` equal to `2000-01-01` because I know that no areas merged before 2000. I can then consider that the origin of my areas story is year 2000. The other thing is about `end_date` that I set to `2100-01-01` to avoid using `infinity`.

This is certainly not the best option (sorry @Evan Carroll!) but it does the job perfectly for me and I don't have enough time to deeply re-organize my data (unfortunately...).

Anyway, thanks to all for help provided!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when an area is merged and its code is reused, you have that information, but when an area is merged and its code is deprecated, you don't have it. In other words, you don't have the information that an area is deprecated.

Now, I see two solutions. First, keep the schemas as is and whenever an area is deprecated, add a new row as it was a new area and just states it is deprecated, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO myTable(code, area, change_date)
VALUES(86001, 'deprecated', '2015-01-01')
```

So in your query it will show as `'deprecated'` or you filter it out.

A second, and possible best option, is to have a new column that states when (and if) an area was deprecated:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD deprecated DATE;
UPDATE myTable SET deprecated = '2015-01-01' WHERE gid = 1;
```

So, on your query you can simple add the filter:

```
(deprecated IS NULL OR deprecated >= '2016-01-01')
```

The full code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (code) code, area, change_date
FROM myTable
WHERE change_date < '2016-01-01'
    AND (deprecated IS NULL OR deprecated >= '2016-01-01')
ORDER BY code, change_date DESC;
```

As another option for non-deprecated areas, you can set them as `'infinity'` instead of `NULL`, so the query does not need the `deprecated IS NULL` condition, as `'infinity'` will always be higher or equal than any other non-null value.

Comment: Thanks @MatheusOI ! I have not enough time to test your suggestions right now. I keep your post and come back to comment them as soon as I can.

Comment: This is perfect! I did not know `infinity` which is a very good option here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest that you clean up the schema. What you want is something like this..

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(gid, code, area, change_date, parent, depth) AS (                                                                    SELECT gid, code, area, change_date, null::int, 0                                                                                   FROM foo                                                                                                                            WHERE change_date = '2000-01-01'::date                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  UNION ALL                                                                                                                         

  SELECT null, null, foo.area, foo.change_date, t.code, depth+1                                                                     
  FROM t                                                                                                                            
  JOIN foo ON (                                                                                                                     
    (                                                                                                                               
      ( foo.code BETWEEN t.code AND t.code+1 )                                                                                      
      AND foo.gid != t.gid                                                                                                          
    )                                                                                                                               
    AND foo.change_date >= t.change_date                                                                                            
    AND foo.change_date != '2000-01-01'                                                                                             
  )                                                                                                                                 
)                                                                                                                                   
SELECT * FROM t AS t1;
```

Run that query, and you'll see a result set like this...

```
 gid | code  |      area      | change_date | parent | depth 
-----+-------+----------------+-------------+--------+-------
   1 | 86001 | Martin Land    | 2000-01-01  |        |     0
   2 | 86002 | Bulwers Land   | 2000-01-01  |        |     0
   4 | 86003 | Coveral Land   | 2000-01-01  |        |     0
   5 | 86004 | Big Tom Area   | 2000-01-01  |        |     0
   6 | 86005 | Small Tom Area | 2000-01-01  |        |     0
     |       | Martin-Bulwers | 2015-01-01  |  86001 |     1
     |       | Martin-Bulwers | 2015-01-01  |  86002 |     1
     |       | Tom Land       | 2016-01-01  |  86003 |     1
     |       | Tom Land       | 2016-01-01  |  86004 |     1
```

Simply add the `WHERE` clause to get what you want (or a better version).

Not there are some problems with this method and I believe them to be inherent in your data. `Tom Land` has code less than that of `Small Tom Area` and a gid one higher than `Coveral Land` with a newer date.

Here, I'm assuming that you're `change_date` of `2000-01-01` is a result of likely having a date-column that can't accept nulls. What I would do is update the table and

1. Store the parent id.
2. Run this

   ```
   UPDATE foo
   SET date = NULL
   WHERE dates = 2000-01-01
   ```

I would do this because

1. `infinity` is a bad idea:

   - It has no relation to the data.
   - It has [limited third party support. **I have retrospection.**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/224734/6052)
   - It stored as a special-cased HIGHEST date under the hood
2. Your schema is less useful

   - You're describing your lower bounds AND your upper bounds with nonsense to ease querying.
   - You're still not storing parent even though this inherently a logical problem.

If you need you can turn the Recursive CTE into a view which is all the more better.

I think you need to make a better schema anyway, but that *infinity* is not the answer here. You need *hierarchy*.

Comment: Fisrt of all, thank you much for your answer! The problem is that I don't really understand your proposal. `Martin-Bulwers` and `Tom Land` don't have any code in your result set? They do have one, I have no choice about that as it is administrative changes I have to follow. Then, `Martin-Bulwers` has `86002` and `Tom Land`  has `86004`. How could I select the areas for a given year?

Comment: @wiltomap look forward to answering that question, and clearing this up but first I have to know it's possible and I'm not yet sure it is. My question on Tom Land must be answered above. My answer speaks specifically to your problem the other answer is generic. This problem specifically can't be solved as far as I can see with either answer. Which is convenient for the chosen answer which chose to abstract the problem.

Comment: .@Evan Carrol: thanks for being so dedicated to this post! `Tom Land` is the result of `Big Tom` (`86004`) and `Small Tom` (`86005`) areas merge. The **administration** decided to **keep one of the parent codes** for the new merged one (`86004`). I have no choice but taking it into account... So, I think this has to be treated without relying on gid or code. I guessed that relying on change dates only would allow to list the different areas of a given year. By the way, the solution is not necessarily a single table. Have another read to my initial post again, I can hardly make it more clear.

Comment: If we're not relying on GID or Code, the question then remains how do we differentiate between `Coveral Land` and `Big Tom` both of which have the same date? How do we know `Coveral Land` is not also in `Tom Land`?

Comment: They don't have the same code... :-) I mean that in the query, I need to list distinct codes for a given year (I obviously rely on codes to identify the areas). If one code is showing on multiple rows, then the stored dates should be different in order to know if the area existed on a given year or not.

Comment: You already said "without relying on gid or code", so I'm confused on how we write the logic to properly rely on it so that we catch both mergers.

Comment: Just upload them somewhere and link them to the question, if you can. I take emails but if I'm doing private work, it's for paid consulting: there is otherwise a simple problem. We need to make a hierarchy out of your dataset and I can't see a method of doing it out of the data presented here. You can even write the answer in English. *X is a merger of A, and B because it fits <this criteria> and other options are excluded because of <exclusion criteria>* for both `x=Big Tom` and `x=Martin-Bulwers` what is the value of `<this criteria>` and `<exclusion criteria>`?